# Hypernym for "audio podcast", "radio drama", and "audiobook"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I'm setting up my media library to contain music, movies, shows, audio podcasts, radio dramas, and audiobooks.

I would like audio podcasts, radio dramas, and audiobooks to be in the same category, but I can't think of any term that includes all three. (The closest I can think of is *Non-Music Audio*.)

Is there any good collective term for audio podcasts, radio dramas, and audiobooks?

Comment: (Audio) recordings?

Comment: Maybe Audio (Voice) as opposed to Audio (Music) and Video

Comment: Okay, I think that's right, this is a duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoken Audio / Spoken Word / Humanoid Sounds

Comment: Thank you! I'd upvote, but I'm brand new on this community, low rep.

Comment: "Humanoid Sounds" could include a whole lotta other non-verbal sounds! lol!

Comment: A little more detail (e.g., establishing the actual currency of these terms for this thing, preferably with links) would make this a better answer. "Spoken Word" for instance, is a long-established hypernym for this genre of *recorded* sound, but of late the term seems to have been applied to a vogue in poetry (not to be confused with Vogon poetry--but then, maybe on second thought . . .), to the point where the [Wikipedia article of that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoken_word) uses that sense.

Answer (score 1):

*[Narrative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrative)* recordings:

> noun
>
> 1 :  something that is *narrated* :  story, account

*[narrate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrated)*

> : to say the words that are heard as part of (a movie, television
>   show, etc.) and that describe what is being seen :
>   <sub>*Merriam-Webster*</sub>